# Xcode 9 hangs on upload

Tags: ios, xcode, build, upload

I'm trying to upload a build on AppStore via Xcode 9.
I've been struggling since last Thursday and unfortunately with no success.
The process hangs on: "Fetching AppStore configuration". I'm unable to pass this step. I also tried uploading through Xcode 8 but there is also a problem regarding SSL connection.

Any advice, solution highly appreciated.

Comment: Try using Application Loader.

Comment: I have the same issue also when I try to export the archive.

Comment: Did you get past it? I also have the problem...